# Bash Pattern Matching

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying to use pattern matching to find all files within a directory that have an extension of either .jpg or jpeg.

`ls *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]` <- this obviously will only find the .jpeg file extension. The question is, how do I make the `[eE` optional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match harder.

```
ls *.[jJ][pP]{[eE],}[gG]
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as the standard (simple) glob patterns, bash ≥4.0 has *extended* globbing.
It is [*off* by default](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#extglob). To turn it on, use:  `shopt -s extglob`

With `extglob` you have access to extended regular expression patterns as well as the standard patterns.  Furthermore, in your particular situation, you can tailor your glob's behaviour even further by enabling a [case insensitive glob](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#extglob), which is also off by default. To turn it on, use: `shopt -s nocaseglob`

Enabling `extglob` does not alter how standard globs work. You can mix the two forms. The only issue is that you have to be aware of the special extended regex syntax. eg, In the example below, the only part of it which is an extended regex, is `?(e)`.  The rest is standard glob expansion, with case-insensitivity enabled.

The extended-regex, case-insensitive  glob for your situation is:

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
ls -l *.jp?(e)g
```

You can find more info and examples at: [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

Comment: Actually, Bash got extended globbing in bash-2.02-alpha1 (i.e. a _long_ time ago - like 15 years). Whether it's on or off by default can be chosen when `./configure` is run (i.e. prior to compilation). In fact the version in which it was introduced is shown at the link you gave for its default setting.